# Redirecting to different action upon failed restriction in deadbolt2

Tags: permissions, playframework-2.2, play-authenticate, deadbolt, deadbolt-2

With deadbolt2 and play-authenticate I can define restrictions on the controller and action level based on a user's roles and permissions. If the current user does not satisfy these restrictions, `AbstractDeadboltHandler.onAuthFailure` in the configured deadbolt handler is called.

Now, what I'd like to achieve is to have different user roles (e.g. trial_user, basic_user, pro_user, admin, …) and allow only some users to call specific actions (in other words: block the other users from calling the action. For instance, a trial_user should not be allowed to create new posts).

This works so far, as users without the required roles cannot call the action. But, here is the problem: As soon as a restriction is not met, the user gets redirected to the generic "auth failure" page which asks him to log in. This is not *correct* in my opinion, since the user is actually logged in and is only lacking a certain role (or has a role which must not perform the action).

How can I react in the `onAuthFailure` method on this case? How can I differentiate between "user not logged in" and "user does not have a certain role". Obviously, always asking the user to login is not the right thing to do. I'd prefer to have a notice "You do not have the rights to access the page".

How can I know the specific reason behind an auth failure? Is that even possible with deadbolt2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try implementing your DeadboltHandler#onAuthFailure method in this way

```
public F.Promise<Result> onAuthFailure(Http.Context context,
                                       String content) {
    Subject subject = getSubject();
    if (subject == null) {
        // 401 Unauthorized
    } else {
        // 403 Forbidden
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is there a way I can find out which role was missing? I.e. display/redirect a different error message depending on the missing role? ("You must be admin", "Please upgrade your account").

Comment: Not at the moment, but it's a good idea.  When I get time, I'll add a report object into the request scope detailing why the authorisation failed.